# Fortify does not trust Java System properties

Tags: java, properties, command, code-injection, fortify

I am trying to fork a process using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String[] javaCmd = {"java", "-cp", classpath, ...};

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
// ...
builder.command(javaCmd)
// ...
```

Fortify reports a Command Injection vulnerability because the `javaCmd` is "built from untrusted data". Fortify is right because System properties are mutuble: `System.setProperty()` which makes them dangerous to use in running system commands.

I have failed to find alternatives to `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, and I'm wondering if anybody has an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The entire command is one giant walking vulnerability. Or not. Security is not black and white. It's shades of gray. This code is not quite entirely white, but it's a light gray (that is: It gives attackers some routes in, but these routes aren't usually available on properly configured systems and the few ways 'in' usually take as given far more dire and direct routes, which makes the opened attack surfaces mostly moot).

TL;DR: Warning's dumb, tell fortify to ignore this one, also, your processes for security probably need an update. Also, this code is highly likely not to actually do what you want. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to write code that does do what you want; apologies for being the bearer of bad news.

In a little more detail:

In particular, "I shall just deal with every fortify warning by not quite following through on a general analysis but just by writing the nearest thing I can think of that gets rid of it" is a fine, fine way to think you've written secure code without actually doing so.

You must understand what fortify is driving at. You must then figure out what the attack surface actually is, and either not accept this (And therefore change / remove *ALL* code that exposes it), or accept it, and document that this attack surface is irrelevant. In this case, the second option (accept it, document it, and move on) sounds like the right move for virtually all imaginable scenarios.

In this specific instance, your code as written has 2 different attack surfaces:

### Disk access leads to being compromised

You're running `java`. Just like that. A relative path. You have no idea what java that will run, and you definitely have no guarantee whatsoever it'll be the same java that your current JVM is from. It could easily be a malicious script. This would require that the attacker finds a way to put that script in a folder that is on the path. For non-root users, `.` is often on the path, and first on the path, so if this is e.g. a server and an attacker can manage to make the server save a file in its own directory, boom. There you go. Your server is now compromised.

That fortify doesn't warn against this is in error; in general relative paths are just a bad idea, if not for security reasons, then for stability reasons: This is not going to work on many, many servers. It is unfortunately basically impossible to reliably invoke a second JVM from a first in a platform and deployment indepedent fashion. That's why the true solution generally is to straight up either avoid it, or set up explicit OS-bound scripts that take care of this (and then run the script, with an absolute path).

### Compromising the system property

Yes, if sonme attacker manages to entice your JVM to run `System.setProperty("java.class.path")`, then they can compromise your machine. **But this is utterly ridiculous**. You should immediately forget about this attack surface because it's zero length.

How likely is it that you run `System.setProperty(untrustedUserInput, someOtherUntrustedUserInput);`? Go ahead, search your code base. It's.. *HIGHLY* unlikely to be there. It is possible that some attacker can coerce your server to run *any* bytecode it wants (this would require an open security leak such as a PNG parser that has buffer overflows or what not; that means it's either an attacker with a 0-day, or your processes to ensure your server is patched in a timely fashion are broken in which case you have far bigger problems). If an attacker can do this, they can set the property, yes.

They can also just straight up `ProcessBuilder` whatever the want, so, the point is entirely moot. You're focussing on the rock that is beside the gigantic mountain and decreeing it the highest point in the land.

Thus, to conclude: the fortify warning is in this case **silly** and should be completely ignored. However, this code *IS* definitely opening up some attack surfaces; not particularly big ones, though. In particular, if nobody can log into this box or write into the user-that-runs-this-JVM-process's directories (which surely they should not, or edit paths!) - you're fine. And if that's not the case, you have bigger problems.

This is how security works: You write this stuff down and you keep reviewing all across the process (not just the code, the docs, the checks, do bi-yearly interviews with the sysops to check they read the docs and are following the directives). You can't shut down every attack surface. You can merely create awareness of them and ensure that they cannot be abused.

I don't think there is a creative way to make fortify shut up (perhaps by invoking processbuilder via reflection, fortify probably won't figure it out), but all that does is **reduce** security. The only right solution here is to ditch fortify entirely (that's a bit drastic, perhaps), or to use it how one should use it: Take the places it founds as a **non-exhaustive** list of code to **analyse**. Not as 'this is a list of stuff I need to fix and then my code is secure'. This analysis should suffice, and therefore, stick the appropriate annotation or comment or whatever it takes to tell fortify that you've manually accepted this one and that it should no longer tell you about it.

### The true solution

Don't do this. At all. Try to find a way to do whatever needs doing without invoking a new JVM at all. If that's not on the table, redefine how it works: Instead of 'clone this VM with the same classpath as this VM', instead think about 'run a new VM which is not neccessarily a clone of this VM, in the sense that the actual JVM I start may not be the same executable that this VM is powered by, and the classpath is configured explicitly or at least elsewhere'. In other words, if you must, document that proper setup of this server requires the creation of a script in a specific location, with access rights configured appropriately, which boots a JVM with a specific classpath.